# React date format issue in ExpenseDate.js

Tags: reactjs, date, react-props

```
 1. Below is ExpenseDate.js------------------------------------------------------------
    
    const ExpenseDate = (props) =>
 {   const year = props.date.getFullYear();  
    const month = props.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });  
    const day = props.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
    
      return (
        <div>
          <div>{month}</div>
          <div>{year}</div>
          <div>{day}</div>
        </div>   ); };
    
    export default ExpenseDate;
    
    
  2.  Below is ExpenseForm.js----------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    
    const ExpenseForm = (props) => {   // const [userInput,
    setUserInput] = useState({   //   enteredTitle: "",   //  
    enteredAmount: "",   //   enteredDate: ""   // });   const
    [enteredTitle, setEnteredTitle] = useState("");   const
    [enteredAmount, setEnteredAmount] = useState("");   const
    [enteredDate, setEnteredDate] = useState("");   const
    TitleChangeHandler = (event) => {
        // setUserInput({
        //   ...userInput,
        //   enteredTitle: event.target.value
        // });
        setEnteredTitle(event.target.value);   };   const AmountChangeHandler = (event) => {
        // setUserInput({
        //   ...userInput,
        //   enteredAmount: event.target.value
        // });
        setEnteredAmount(event.target.value);   };   const DateChangeHandler = (event) => {
        // setUserInput({
        //   ...userInput,
        //   enteredDate: event.target.value
        // });
        setEnteredDate(event.target.value);   };   const submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const expenseData = {
          title: enteredTitle,
          amount: enteredAmount,
          date: new Date(enteredDate)
        };
        props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData);
        setEnteredTitle("");
        setEnteredAmount("");
        setEnteredDate("");   };   return (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <div className="form-controls">
            <div className="form=control">
              <label>Title</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={enteredTitle}
                onChange={TitleChangeHandler}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form=control">
              <label>Amount</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                value={enteredAmount}
                onChange={AmountChangeHandler}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form=control">
              <label>Date</label>
              <input type="date" value={enteredDate} onChange={DateChangeHandler} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-controls">
            <button type="submit">Add Expense</button>
          </div>
        </form>   ); };
    
    export default ExpenseForm;
    
   

   3. Below is App.js------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    import "./styles.css"; import { useState } from "react"; import
    Expenses from "./Expenses"; import NewExpense from "./NewExpense";
    const DUMMY_EXPENSES = [   {
        id: "e1",
        title: "toilet paper",
        amount: 94.12,
        date: new Date(2022, 7, 14)   },   {
        id: "e2",
        title: "New TV",
        amount: 89.1,
        date: new Date(2023, 8, 19)   },   {
        id: "e3",
        title: "New fridge",
        amount: 99.1,
        date: new Date(2023, 5, 6)   } ]; export default function App() {   const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(DUMMY_EXPENSES);
    
      const AddexpenseHandler = (expense) => {
        setExpenses((prevExpenses) => {
          return [expenses, ...prevExpenses];
        });   };   return (
        <div className="App">
          <NewExpense onAddexpense={AddexpenseHandler} />
          <Expenses items={expenses} />
        </div>   ); }
    
 4. Below is Expenses.js  -----------------------------------------------


import { useState } from "react";
import ExpenseFilter from "./ExpenseFilter";
import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem";
const Expenses = (props) => {
  const [filteredYear, setFilteredYear] = useState("2020");
  const filterChangeHandler = (selectedYear) => {
    setFilteredYear(selectedYear);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ExpenseFilter
        selected={filteredYear}
        onChangeFilter={filterChangeHandler}
      />
      {props.items.map((expense) => (
        <ExpenseItem
          title={expense.title}
          amount={expense.amount}
          date={expense.date}
        />
      ))}
      {/* <ExpenseItem
        title={props.items[0].title}
        amount={props.items[0].amount}
        date={props.items[0].date}
      />
      <ExpenseItem
        title={props.items[1].title}
        amount={props.items[1].amount}
        date={props.items[1].date}
      />
      <ExpenseItem
        title={props.items[2].title}
        amount={props.items[2].amount}
        date={props.items[2].date}
      /> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Expenses;
```

---

We have 4 separate files here. I'm getting error in the line -->
const year = props.date.getFullYear(); ---
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFullYear')
How to fix this, please elaborate. Tried const year= new Date.getFullYear(), this doesnot work. Please help me with this issue. Its better if you write the code in comment section.

Comment: So buttom line looks like {expenses} is undefined when <Expenses> is being rendered. i suspect that during the first mount <Expenses> is being returned before expenses state is set to DUMMY_EXPENSES. try to conditionaly render Expenses only if the state is updated, otherwise the first render gives you the error because it is still undefined and that breaks your code. try <expenses && Expenses items={expenses} />

Comment: Throws error, doesnot work